# How to reduce (or optimize) size of recently built LFS?

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-from-scratch

As the title shows, I've recently built an LFS (version 8.3), with jhalfs.
So with `du -h`, the size of the whole partition is about 4.5 GB
(I've already deleted all the files in /sources).

Executing this command that shows what are the big files in the system : `du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 10` , shows this result :

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know how can I optimize and reduce my partition (what files / packages /or repertories to erase) without breaking the OS ?
The goal is reaching an operating system that turns around 400 or 300 MB.
Thank you

Comment: You don't need `/tools` after the build is complete, removing it will cut the system by half immediately. You can also delete documentation, and strip debugging symbols from the binaries. But even if you do these things I'm not sure you're going to get it that small, I could be wrong.

Comment: Hello, I've already deleted /tools, can you tell me what do you mean by strip debugging symbols ? I'm still a newbie at Linux so i'm not sure what it means. Thank you in advance

Comment: If there are any docs (manpages?), you can toss them out too

Comment: Thank you, i'll look it up @ti7

Answer (score 0):

Aside from removing `/tools` and maybe also docs (`/usr/share/doc`, `/usr/share/man`) you can also strip debugging symbols from all the libraries and executables. This is done using [strip(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html) utility; detailed instructions can be found in the LFS book, section ["Stripping Again"](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/9.1/chapter06/strippingagain.html).